# Unmarshal xml node containing data and child

Tags: xml, go

Im not sure this is valid xml, unfortunately its what I'm having to deal with - looking for suggestions on how to accomplish.

my xml looks like this:

```
<report>
    <sort>
        <field>type<order>ascending</order></field>
    </sort>
</report>
```

I am attempting to unmarshall into the following structs:

```
type Sort struct {
    Field string `xml:"field"`
    Order string `xml:"field>order"`
}

type Report struct {
    Sort Sort       `xml:"sort"`
}
```

unfortunately this is throwing the error:

> Unmarshalling error: v7.Sort field "Field" with tag "field" conflicts
>   with field "Order" with tag "field>order"

Is there a built in way of achieving this or am I looking at some custom unmarshalling

UPDATE:
At least according to this answer it appears this should be valid if slightly ugly xml: [Can a XML element contain text and child elements at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130228/can-a-xml-element-contain-text-and-child-elements-at-the-same-time)

Comment: It's definitely not valid XML, `<field>` is not terminated and just plain invalid. Don't try to parse it as xml.

Comment: sorry corrected xml sample, field field is terminated (typo) - but i think still invalid as data and node inside node

Comment: Looks valid, it's just that order is not a direct sibling of field but of a text node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single XML element can only be mapped to a single struct field, and your model tries to map `<field>` to 2 struct fields, so it's not allowed.

The character data of `<field>` and the child element `<order>` are at the same "level", they are siblings, so they must be in the same struct. But they are different types of nodes: to get the character data, use the `xml:",chardata"` struct tag, and to get the value of the `<order>` child element, use the `xml:"order"` struct tag.

So use the following Go model:

```
type Field struct {
    Value string `xml:",chardata"`
    Order string `xml:"order"`
}

type Sort struct {
    Field Field `xml:"field"`
}

type Report struct {
    Sort Sort `xml:"sort"`
}
```

Parsing your input XML into this model:

```
func main() {
    var r Report
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(src), &r)
    fmt.Printf("%+v %v", r, err)
}

const src = `<report>
    <sort>
        <field>type<order>ascending</order></field>
    </sort>
</report>`
```

Output is (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zbkYrYb67t4)):

```
{Sort:{Field:{Value:type Order:ascending}}} <nil>
```

Since `Sort` only contains a single `Field` field, we can simplify the model to this:

```
type Field struct {
    Value string `xml:",chardata"`
    Order string `xml:"order"`
}

type Report struct {
    SortField Field `xml:"sort>field"`
}
```

And it works the same way, gives a similar output (try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wKvFmIr0IPi)):

```
{SortField:{Value:type Order:ascending}} <nil>
```

Comment: I was just poking around with chardata - yip this works - thanks for thorough answer