# Parsing mixed content XML element with Jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson, deserialization

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12130228/6413377) it is ok to have XML like

```
<root>
  asdasda
  <sub>qwertyuiop</sub>
</root>
```

However using Jackson XmlMapper (by default) to this kind of class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Getter @Setter
public class Root {
    private String sub;
}
```

gives an error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "" (class org.example.jackson.unwrap.TestIt1$Root), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "sub"]) ...

Ok, I can add

```
xmlMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

and I will get everything else but root text 'asdasda'.

What should I add to have 'asdasda' also in some field of class `Root` instead of just ignoring it?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it is not supported at all. [From Jackson docs Known Limitations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml#known-limitations)

> Tree Model (JsonNode, ObjectMapper.readTree()) is based on JSON content model and it does not match exactly with XML infoset
> Mixed content (both textual content and elements as children of an element) not supported: **text, if any, will be lost**